# How to get Color from GetCssAttribute in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, nunit

i would like to ask you what is the equivalent in c#
In jUnit i can use

```
row = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'colours')]/h1"));
string hexColor = Color.FromString(row.GetCssValue("color")).asHex();
```

but what is the equivalent in Nunit (C#)?

Comment: How does the unit test provider have anything to do with this? Are you talking about the `asHex()` method call at the end?

Comment: And jUnit is a Java unit testing framework. Are you trying to rewrite this C# code in Java?

Comment: It looks like your code example is mixing Java and C#. Can you post the Java code and note which parts you need help with converting to C#?